Average kinetic energy of a non-relativistic electron in beta decay
I am trying to show that (a bird told me), in a beta decay, the average kinetic energy carried off by a non-relativistic electron is $E_0 / 3$. I have derived that, for the states, a distribution
$$dN =  \frac{1}{4\pi^4} (E_0 - E_e)^2 p_e^2 \ d p_e \tag{1}$$ by ignoring the recoil of the nucleus and using the relation $E_0 = E_e + E_\nu$. (I am aware that in the relativistic case I can take $p_e = E_e$ and show that $\langle E_e \rangle = E_0 / 2$.)
I thought of two different attempts, none of them brought me to the right conclusion.
Attempt 1: I use the distribution to calculate the expected value of kinetic energy $kE = \frac{p_e^2}{2m_e}$.
$$\langle k E \rangle = \int_0^{E_0} \frac{1}{4\pi^4} \frac{p_e^2}{2m_e} \cdot (E_0 - E_e)^2 p_e^2 \ d p_e $$
This doesn't work when I work out the algebra because of a factor of $m_e$.
Attempt 2: I disregard the distribution above and think about the problem as a two-body decay.
Electron has momentum $p_e$ and energy $\frac{p_e^2}{2m_e}$. Neutrino has momentum (and energy) $p_\nu$. By energy conservation have $E_0 = E_e + E_\nu$, and by momentum conservation have $p_e = -p_\nu$. Thus
$$E_0 = \frac{p_e^2}{2m_e} + p_e$$
The solution is $p_e = \pm \sqrt{2m_e E_0} - m_e$, but

I am not even sure if this approach is correct, as it implies there is only one possible momentum for the electron
It still doesn't yield the desired $kE = E_0 / 3$ relation.

(Everything is in natural units, and eqn. 1 may not be entirely correct. Many thanks in advance.)
